# Canvas absolute and relative coordinates, delta pixels retrieval

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

In this test script I draw a square I may zoom in by using the mouse wheel.
If I right click inside a cell I get the right cell coordinates (not x and y, but column and row): this is exactly what I expect it to write to the console in the background.
If I, instead, move the canvas by pressing the mouse left button and dragging it somewhere else, the coordinates are not right any more.

Where do I get the delta x and delta y (or offsets) to give back the right info?

FYI:
1) get_pos() is the method that does the check and produces the result.
2) the following code has been tested on Ubuntu 16.10 (with the latest updates) running Python 3.5.2.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class GriddedMazeCanvas(tk.Canvas):

def almost_centered(self, cols, rows):

    width = int(self['width'])
    height = int(self['height'])
    cell_dim = self.settings['cell_dim']
    rows = rows % height
    cols = cols % width

    w = cols * cell_dim
    h = rows * cell_dim

    if self.zoom < 0:
        raise ValueError('zoom is negative:', self.zoom)

    zoom = self.zoom
    if self.drawn() and 1 != zoom:
        w *= zoom
        h *= zoom

    h_shift = (width - w) // 2
    v_shift = (height - h) // 2

    return [h_shift, v_shift,
            h_shift + w, v_shift + h]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'settings' not in kwargs:
        raise ValueError("'settings' not passed.")
    settings = kwargs['settings']
    del kwargs['settings']

    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.config(highlightthickness=0)

    self.settings = settings
    self.bind_events()

def draw_maze(self, cols, rows):

    self.cols = cols
    self.rows = rows

    if self.not_drawn():
        self.cells = {}
        self.cell_dim = self.settings['cell_dim']
        self.border_thickness = self.settings['border_thickness']
        self.zoom = 1

    self.delete(tk.ALL)

    maze, coords = self._draw_maze(cols, rows, fix=False)
    lines = self._draw_grid(coords)

    return maze, lines

def _draw_maze(self, cols, rows, fix=True):
    data = self.settings

    to_max = data['to_max']
    border_thickness = data['border_thickness']
    poligon_color = data['poligon_color']
    poligon_border_color = data['poligon_border_color']

    coords = self.almost_centered(cols, rows)

    if fix:
        # Fix for the disappearing NW borders
        if to_max == cols:
            coords[0] += 1
        if to_max == rows:
            coords[1] += 1

    maze = self.create_rectangle(*coords,
                                 fill=poligon_color,
                                 outline=poligon_border_color,
                                 width=border_thickness,
                                 tag='maze')
    return maze, coords

def _draw_grid(self, coords):
    data = self.settings
    poligon_border_color = data['poligon_border_color']
    cell_dim = data['cell_dim']

    if coords is None:
        if self.not_drawn():
            raise ValueError('The maze is still uninitialized.')
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.almost_centered(self.cols, self.rows)
    else:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = coords

    zoom = self.zoom
    if self.drawn() and 1 != zoom:
        if self.zoom < 1:
            self.zoom = zoom = 1
            print('no zooming below 1.')
        else:
            cell_dim *= zoom

    lines = []

    for i, x in enumerate(range(x1, x2, cell_dim)):
        line = self.create_line(x, y1, x, y2,
                                fill=poligon_border_color,
                                tags=('grid', 'grid_hl_{}'.format(i)))
        lines.append(line)

    for i, y in enumerate(range(y1, y2, cell_dim)):
        line = self.create_line(x1, y, x2, y,
                                fill=poligon_border_color,
                                tags=('grid', 'grid_vl_{}'.format(i)))
        lines.append(line)

    return lines

def drawn(self):
    return hasattr(self, 'cells')

def not_drawn(self):
    return not self.drawn()

def bind_events(self):

    self.bind('<Button-4>', self.onZoomIn)
    self.bind('<Button-5>', self.onZoomOut)

    self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.onScrollStart)
    self.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.onScrollMove)
    self.tag_bind('maze', '<ButtonPress-3>', self.onMouseRight)

def onScrollStart(self, event):
    print(event.x, event.y, self.canvasx(event.x), self.canvasy(event.y))
    self.scan_mark(event.x, event.y)

def onMouseRight(self, event):
    col, row = self.get_pos(event)
    print('zoom:', self.zoom, '  col, row:', col, row)

def onScrollMove(self, event):
    delta = event.x, event.y
    self.scan_dragto(*delta, gain=1)

def onZoomIn(self, event):
    if self.not_drawn():
        return

    max_zoom = 9

    self.zoom += 1
    if self.zoom > max_zoom:
        print("Can't go beyond", max_zoom)
        self.zoom = max_zoom
        return

    print('Zooming in.', event.num, event.x, event.y, self.zoom)
    self.draw_maze(self.cols, self.rows)

def onZoomOut(self, event):
    if self.not_drawn():
        return

    self.zoom -= 1
    if self.zoom < 1:
        print("Can't go below one.")
        self.zoom = 1
        return

    print('Zooming out.', event.num, event.x, event.y, self.zoom)
    self.draw_maze(self.cols, self.rows)

def get_pos(self, event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    cols, rows = self.cols, self.rows
    cell_dim, zoom = self.cell_dim, self.zoom
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.almost_centered(cols, rows)

    print('x1, y1, x2, y2:', x1, y1, x2, y2,
          '  bbox:', self.bbox('maze'))
    if not (x1 <= x <= x2 and y1 <= y <= y2):
        print('Here we are out of bounds.')
        return None, None

    scale = zoom * cell_dim

    col = (x - x1) // scale
    row = (y - y1) // scale

    return col, row


class CanvasButton(ttk.Button):

def freeze_origin(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'origin'):
        canvas = self.canvas
        self.origin = canvas.xview()[0], canvas.yview()[0]

def reset(self):
    canvas = self.canvas
    x, y = self.origin
    canvas.yview_moveto(x)
    canvas.xview_moveto(y)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'canvas' not in kwargs:
        raise ValueError("'canvas' not passed.")
    canvas = kwargs['canvas']
    del kwargs['canvas']

    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.config(command=self.reset)

    self.canvas = canvas


root = tk.Tk()

settings = {'cell_dim': 3,
            'to_max': 200,
            'border_thickness': 1,
            'poligon_color': '#F7F37E',
            'poligon_border_color': '#AC5D33'}

frame = ttk.Frame(root)
canvas = GriddedMazeCanvas(frame,
                           settings=settings,
                           width=640,
                           height=480)
button = CanvasButton(frame, text='Reset', canvas=canvas)
button.freeze_origin()

canvas.draw_maze(20, 10)

canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.NSEW)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at a [previously answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811263/python-tkinter-convert-canvas-coordinate-to-window-coordinate?rq=1), I learned how to find the delta x and delta y I was looking for.

So, the solution is:

```
    def get_pos(self, event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        cols, rows = self.cols, self.rows
        cell_dim, zoom = self.cell_dim, self.zoom
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.almost_centered(cols, rows)

        # the following line stores deltax and deltay into x0, y0 
        x0, y0 = int(self.canvasx(0)), int(self.canvasy(0))

        # then it is trivial to compute the solution
        xa, ya = x1 - x0, y1 - y0
        xb, yb = x2 - x0, y2 - y0

        if not (xa <= x <= xb and ya <= y <= yb):
            print('Here we are out of bounds.')
            return None, None

        scale = zoom * cell_dim

        col = (x - xa) // scale
        row = (y - ya) // scale

        return col, row
```