# How to determine the cursor's position on the canvas after scrolling?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm using a canvas and I want to know the cursor's position, I use `canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)` and in the callback `event.x` and `event.y`
But my issue comes when I use a `Scrollbar` to move the content inside the canvas: I want the cursor's position to be adjusted by the `Scrollbar` offset.

```
def callback(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
    #need these x and y to by adjusted with the Scrollbar offset


root = tk.Tk()
yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root)
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, yscrollcommand = yscrollbar 
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
yscrollbar.config(command = canvas.yview)
yscrollbar.pack()
```

Comment: Please provide the [mcve].

Comment: I don't believe above code is complete, please verify that it is.

Comment: It's all right there in the documentation. [canvasx](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.canvasx-method) and [canvasy](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.canvasy-method) methods.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated you can use the **canvas.canvasx** / **canvas.canvasy** methods:

```
class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, app):
        # Initialize canvas with scrollable region and mouse down binding
        self.canvas = ...     

    #  Exemplaric mouse down method
    def onMouseDown(self, event):
        # Get the position on the scrollable canvas
        xOnCanvas = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
        yOnCanvas = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
```

Reference answer: [How to convert Tkinter canvas coordinate to window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811263/how-to-convert-tkinter-canvas-coordinate-to-window)

Answer (score 0):

It's all right there in the documentation. canvasx and canvasy methods. – Bryan Oakley