# Tkinter canvas drag off center

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, draggable, tkinter-canvas

Is there a way to find out how many pixels a scrollbar has scrolled over a canvas in Tkinter? I'm writing an application that drags and drops lines. However, whenever I attempt to drag a line, after I have scrolled some amount, the line automatically centers on the position where the end of the line was, prior to scrolling. My idea is to offset the coordinates by the same amount, so the line stays precisely under the mouse icon while dragging.

```
#output is the canvas
#wires is a list containing the item ID's of all the lines in my project
def moveLine(e):
    outputItem = output.find_withtag('current')
    try:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = output.coords(outputItem)
    except:
        pass

    if len(output.coords(outputItem)) != 0 and outputItem[0] in wires:
        output.coords(outputItem, x0, y0, e.x, e.y)
        output.itemconfig(outputItem, fill='blue')
```

Comment: Does this help answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7811911/7432

Comment: Change `output.coords(outputItem, x0, y0, e.x, e.y)` to `output.coords(outputItem, x0, y0, output.canvasx(e.x), output.canvasy(e.y))`.

Answer (score -3):

There is two ways how to solve this. U can use tkinter widget Scrollbar but that moving icon will be delayed. And second way is to make your own scroll bar (on click event, motion event for slider and dont forget to block Y axis) and on this motion event drag icon and slider at same function. It will be smoother. If u want, i can sent u my code for custom scrollbar.

Comment: Neither of those are a good way to solve this problem. Plus, this answer doesn't have enough details for someone to actually implement the suggestions.